# Поиск и подстановка значений на странице

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, phpstorm, поиск

у меня есть 10 страниц html, у каждой страницы есть `<title>Заголовок1</title>` со своими уникальными, для каждой страницы, значениями.
Далеко ниже в коде у меня есть пустые `<h1></h1>`.

Вопрос: как можно с помощью регулярных выражений заполнить теги `<h1></h1>` теми значениями, которые в `<title></title>`?

Comment: Откуда подставляете-то хоть? Язык какой?

Comment: Работа регулярками с `HTML` - ооооочень плохая идея, к слову.

Comment: Это не язык, это обычный search and replace. Попробуйте [`(<title>([^<]+)</title>[\s\S]*)<h1></h1>` заменить на `$1<h1>$2</h1>`](https://regex101.com/r/2QAmxG/1).

Comment: вы мой спаситель, спасибо. Все работает как надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте регулярное выражение на основе захватывающих групп и обратный ссылках:

```
(<title>([^<]+)</title>[\s\S]*)<h1></h1>
```

Замените на

```
$1<h1>$2</h1>
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/2QAmxG/1)

**Подробности**

- `(<title>([^<]+)</title>[\s\S]*)` - (группа №1) последовательность следующих шаблонов:

  - `<title>` - подстрока `<title>`
  - `([^<]+)` - (группа №2) любые 1+  символов, отличных от `<`
  - `</title>` - подстрока `</title>`
  - `[\s\S]*` - любые 0+  символов
- `<h1></h1>` - подстрока `<h1></h1>`